# Tridion Content Manager Search Host High CPU and Memory

Tags: 2013-sp1, search, solr

I am noticing that the Tridion Content Manager Search Host is consistently running at higher than expected CPU and Memory.

My understanding is that Tridion Content Manager Search Host is just a Tomcat instance hosting SOLR, so why would it require so much CPU and memory?

Looking in `%TRIDION_HOME%\Search\solr-data\tridion\index` the data files inside are constantly churning, changing name and size

[image]

Comment: "the data files inside are constantly churning, changing name and size" - I am sure this is default SOLR behaviour as I have seen it stand alone SOLR setup. There may be huge cpu and memory consumption in case you have a huge amount of content getting updated via multiple authors - Is it the case with your env?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The culprit was Sync-TcmSearchIndex. It was scheduled to run every evening.

This was resulting in a huge Search Queue (items or be indexed) and an ever churning search index

[image]

Sync-TcmSearchIndex is now disabled, and will only be ran as required e.g. out of date search index due to environment sync

To remove items from the queue, you can run Remove-TcmQueueMessages followed by the corresponding queue name:

> **PublishQueue**
>
> Purge publish queue messages.
>
> **DeployQueue**
>
> Purge content deployment messages.
>
> **SearchQueue**
>
> Purge search queue messages.
>
> **WorkflowAgentQueue**
>
> Purge workflow queue messages.
>
> **BatchQueue**
>
> Purge batch queue messages.

Answer (score 1):

You can approach Reindexing Search Queue in another manner. As [following documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-585D5C74-14E0-4E5C-A6A4-8C48B8E188CC) states, you can execute reindex **PER Publication**.

That being said, you can schedule every publication separately at certain intervals to decrease total number of messages. The number of process items will still be the same, only difference is that it will be evenly spread at certain period of time.